# yandex maps в приложении react без react-yandex-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Уважаемое сообщество. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно встроить яндекс карты в приложение react без использования дополнительных оберток? Есть желание использовать возможности API яндекс на полную мощность.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел такое решение:

1 - подключил скрипт карт:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<MY_API_CODE>&apm;lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2 - в App.js сделал следующее:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
}

handleLoad() {
  window.ymaps.ready(() => {
    this.localMap = new window.ymaps.Map('map', {center: this.state.center, zoom: 9}, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'});
  });
}
```